# maximum no of twitter handles I can follow with a twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I have been trying to stream handle details using Twitter streaming API. 
My query is how many maximum no of handles can we follow with a single instance of stream.Till now I have been successfully following around 100 handles. To what limit I can increase my follow handles limit.

Also if we hit the limit how will we know about that. 
Any ideas ?????

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter

> The default access level allows up to 400 track keywords, `5,000` follow userids and 25 0.1-360 degree location boxes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API limit [API TWITTER](https://support.twitter.com/articles/160385)

350 if you have allowed the application to act on your behalf